# Optimizing a fluid grid layout

Tags: html, css, grid, responsive-design

I recently just added a grid layout, but I can't figure out how to make my links work. The grid that I used is the 1140 one at http://cssgrid.net/. I studied the source code of that website, and tried to make my page like theirs, but when I put everything in it made mine worse, and the grid didn't even work. This is how my website is supposed to look http://spencedesign.netau.net/singaporehome.html 
and this is how it does
http://spencedesign.netau.net/home.html
And when you reduce the size, it doesn't look like it's supposed to. When you minimize it I want the pictures(links) to be two per row, then one per row depending on how small the page is. I also want the quote to turn into different rows when it is too small for it. But I can't figure out how to make the page look normal regularly let alone make it look good with a smaller browser. Thanks!

Comment: If you can't get theirs to work following their instructions. Consider http://www.amazium.co.uk/ its pretty easy to implement. Difference is, all the columns must add up to correct amt.

Comment: Okay thanks. This website doesn't have directions, I guess they are assuming that the people know what to do. But I figured it out be erasing the fluid grid, and just changing the container to a percent. Now The only problem I have is that when i resize the webpage, when the rows change the image is not in the center of that

Answer (score 0):

http://goldengridsystem.com/ might have what you're looking for. Folding effect worked for me.